# Magento - product that are not for sale

Tags: magento, catalog, product

Does anyone know how to list products in Magento that are not for sale? I still want the items to appear in the store, but I would like the "Add to cart" function to be disabled. This seems like it would be something that is easy to set up, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set stock level to zero and disable backorders.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I do not want customers to see an "Out of stock" label as that might prevent them from ordering the product through some other method. I would prefer some way to just disable the "Add to Cart" button to prevent purchases. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess that it will be easier to use my approach and suppress the availability message (if it is present in your template). It will be easier because the "add to cart" button presents in many templates and even if you will mute it with some conditional statement you will still have a problem with customers reordering their products from their accounts etc.

Comment: Thanks again for the idea. This is probably what I will end up doing, but I would still prefer some way to just disable sale of the item instead of using the "Out of Stock" method.

Answer (score 1):

Our store uses this on occasion- Adding to what dick mentioned :

1. Set Stock to 0.
2. If your store allows out of stock items to be visible, then this will work immediately.
3. If you do not allow items to be visible once they are out of stock, you'll need to switch this setting in the backend.

Alternatively, you could set up a new product attribute that replaces the add to cart button with something different (more info button, popup, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display for sale only then set it's stock qty to 0 and try to set option from admin like this go to your admin side click on system->configuration->catalog->inventory and set yes **Display Out of Stock Products** so that the product is display on front side without add to cart functionality

Hope this will help you