# Magento - Some products not for sale

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I would like to set some products to "non-saleable", removing the "Add to cart" button and adding a link to contact form.

I'm looking for this solution for a few weeks. Searching, I found this post:

[Magento - product that are not for sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005056/magento-product-that-are-not-for-sale)

At the end of page have this answer:

""Alternatively, you could set up a new product attribute that replaces the add to cart button with something different (more info button, popup, etc)."

How can I do it?

Another post about this subject:

http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/non-salable-products-with-attribute-sets.php

But I can't make it work. Someone could help me with more details?

Answer (score 2):

small tutorial

Create a new attribute "saleable"

- Default Value = yes
- Unique value = no
- values required = yes
- apply to = all product types
- use in quick search = no
- use in advanced searched = no
- comparable on front-end = no
- Use In Layered Navigation = no
- Use for Promo Rule Conditions = no
- Visible on Product View Page on Front-end = no
- Used in Product Listing = no
- Used for Sorting in Product Listing = no

Manage titles

- admin = "Is saleable"
- Default store view = "Is saleable"

Now add it to your attribute set (default) 
create a product or edit a product and define the is "is saleable" attribute.

Now go to the view of your product
/tomcollins.be/app/design/frontend/default//template/catalog/product/view.phtml

put an if statement like this

```
<? if($_product->getData('saleable')): ?>
```

// do what ever you want

```
<?php else: ?>
```

// do what ever you want

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps someone :)

bye

Comment: Like a Charm -> 2014 :) 1.9.1

Comment: Beware - this is not a foolproof solution.  This simply hides the Add to Cart button from your product view, but there are lots of other ways to add an item to a cart.  Many themes have 'Add to Cart' functionality on the category/search listings.  Products can be added on the Wishlist.  I'm sure there are other places too, just be careful

Comment: @mikemike you are right, this solution is only for the product detail page but could be reused at other places aswel

Comment: A quick, but horrible fix, is to mark the product as Out of Stock, and wrap this if statement around the entire purchasing block on the product view.  This way, if you miss somewhere that allows you to add to cart the user will just be redirected to the product page and shown an error, rather than being able to purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your product with an Attribute for example nonsaleable. If that Attribute has value true the product is not saleable.

So now you should take a look at the

Productview in app/design/frontend/your_theme/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml 
and the 
listview app/design/frontend/your_theme/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Now look where in these files are the addtocart buttons are located.
Before this button you place an if nonsable === TRUE { make something } else { addtocart }

Thats the way i would try this.

Sorry for my bad english. I'm still tired :))))

Comment: Thanks, boti. But I need more information. What kind of attribute could I create? "yes/no"? Let's try to write the code together and create a complete tutorial. I'm sure that it will help not only me but a lot of people that search it.

Comment: I will write a tutorial next weekend. I had coded this already. I will post the link here if I completed writing the tutorial. :)

Comment: Thank you, Boti. I'm glad with your attitude. Surely, this tutorial  will help the whole community.

Comment: boti, are you there? I'm anxiously waiting for your code =D. Thank you.

Comment: I really need this tutorial. Where are you, boti?

Answer (score 0):

For all non-for sale products you can set a quantity to 0. It will automatically remove Add to cart. Then you can add link to contact form on all products where add-to-cart doesn't exist. I am coming from Magento Go background so I would do it this way, but I know that with community and enterprise versions you have more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks. But this solution returns the message "Out of stock." I don't want to confuse the client with this alert.

Comment: You could hide out of stock if it's not a problem for you to not have the message if the item is really out of stock.

Comment: Someone has another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will get your desire requirement through this extension because the developer teams for this extension is really very supportive.Please refer below link for extension:

[Click here to get extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/call-for-price-9.html)